# Fails using multiprocessing in decorators (Can't pickle <function test_func>: it's not the same object as __main__.test_func)

Tags: python

I want to use decorator with multiprocessing to stop function test_func by timout.
When I don't use decorator (commited just_func()), process with test_func killed successfully. But when I do the same in decorator function_to_process I've got the error message:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function test_func at 0x000001647506BAE8>: it's not the same object as __main__.test_func  
PS C:\data\temp> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 82, in steal_handle
    _winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, source_pid)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

Could you please help me with what I do wrong and how to fix? In general, I try to create solution for windows part of pytest_timeout to kill test_case by test, not whole test_suite.

Thank you!

Code:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def function_to_process(func):
    def process_wrapper():
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=())
        process.start() 
        process.join(timeout=5)
        if (process.is_alive):
            process.terminate()
        print("done in decorator")        
    return process_wrapper

@function_to_process
def test_func():
    time.sleep(10)

def just_func():
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=test_func, args=())
    process.start()
    process.join(timeout=5)
    if (process.is_alive):
        print("terminated")
        process.terminate()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("start")    
    test_func()
#    just_func()
    print("done in main")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution here [Windows: using decorator with multiprocessing](https://github.com/bitranox/wrapt_timeout_decorator)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).